# Why didn’t Pathaan want to hug him?

Tags: plot-explanation, pathaan

In *Pathaan* (2023), Rubina intentionally gets herself caught on CCTV in Spain,
leading to her capture by Pathaan. Pathaan then arrives at the
control center in Delhi and encounters a group of young team members.
Pathaan assures a young lady, who tries to hug him, that he’ll hug her
only if they survive, and **declares to a bald man that he never
intends to hug him**:

[image]

Why didn’t Pathaan want to hug him?

Comment: It's obviously taken and received as a joke, because the big bald guy grins at the comment

Comment: There's also likely a "no homo" element to it. Hugging a woman? Sure. Hugging *another man*? No way.